# Modifying database in Access with query by insert?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Currently I am modifying my database tables with query SQL and I just have to insert a new row into the table but I can't seem to make my query run and at the moment my code reads:

INSERT INTO Facility( facname)
Values ('Swimming Pool')

Is there a step within the SQL I am missing or something for I genuinely can not figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: How are you trying to *make my query run* specifically? What you've posted doesn't do anything except define what you want to happen; it doesn't make an effort to make it do anything. There's a difference between *I have a hammer, a nail and two pieces of wood. I want to nail these two boards together* and actualy having the boards nailed together - the actual work doesn't start until you pick up the hammer and nails and do something with them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *execute* it:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into Facility (facname) Values ('Swimming Pool')"
```